# Proving two Gaussian random variables are independent given the third: a necessary and sufficient condition for inverse of covariance matrix

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

In my probability class I was given this problem that truly has me stumped:

> Let $ X=(X_1,X_2,X_3) $ be a Gaussian random vector with mean vector zeros, with the 3x3 co variance matrix:
>
> $ \Sigma $
>
> which is invertible so a joint density function exists. Now we define the following: $ p_{13} = {{\Sigma}^{-1}}_{13} =  \frac{1}{|\Sigma|} \begin{bmatrix}
>     \Sigma_{12} & \Sigma_{13} \\
>     \Sigma_{22} & \Sigma_{23} 
>   \end{bmatrix} $
>
> that is the {1,3} entry of the inverse of the covariance matrix $ \Sigma $.
>   We are to prove for the general 3x3 covariance matrix case that given $ X_2 $ the random variables $ X_1,X_3 $ are statistically independent if and only if $ p_{13}=0 $.
>
> As a hint we are advised to look at the conditional expectation of $ X_1 $ given $ X_2,X_3 $ is given by $ \mu = \Sigma_{12} {\Sigma_{22}}^{-1} \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
> x_2 \\
> x_3 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)  $
>
> where we define $ \Sigma_{12} = \begin{bmatrix}
>     E\{X_1X_2\} & E\{X_1X_3\} 
>   \end{bmatrix} $
>
> and we define $ \Sigma_{22} = \begin{bmatrix}
>     E\{{X_2}^2\} & E\{X_2X_3\} \\
>     E\{X_3X_2\} & E\{{X_3}^2\}
>   \end{bmatrix} $

I have no clue as to how to use this clue to show the necessary and sufficient condition for the conditional independence we are given, so I would appreciate anyone giving me help on this here as this clue seems quite vague and unapproachable to me. I thank all kind helpers.